# What is the activation sequence of components after launching Eclipse IDE via the executable?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

After double clicking the Eclipse executable, which files in the installation folder will be activated sequentially?

Comment: Eclipse is an [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) application. [For tracing, you can start Eclipse with the `-debug` argument and an `.option` file](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePerformance/article.html#using-the-build-in-tracing-facilities-of-eclipse).

Comment: Thank you @howlger it's been helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @howlger's instructions in the comment section above and running `eclipse -debug`, the console shows below outputs. We can deduce the processes to three major steps:

1. Start initiation by the platform-specific Eclipse executable
2. Reading configuration file in `eclipse.ini`
3. Reading information of bundles in `configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info` and loading them by their respective start level and order

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1.v20160907-1200\splash.bmp
-launcher path/to/eclipse/.\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444\eclipse_1617.dll
-startup path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-debug
-vm path/to/java/runtime\\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Djava.class.path=path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
Install location:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/
Configuration file:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/configuration/config.ini loaded
Configuration location:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/configuration/
Framework located:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
Loading extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
        eclipse.properties not found
Framework classpath:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar
    file:/path/to/eclipse/plugins/
    file:/path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
Splash location:
    path/to/eclipse/.\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.6.1.v20160907-1200\splash.bmp
Debug options:
    file:/path/to/eclipse/.options loaded
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller (file:/path/to/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632.jar) to method java.net.URLClassLoader.addURL(java.net.URL)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.eclipse.osgi.storage.FrameworkExtensionInstaller
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Finding activator for org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632 [0]
Starting org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632 [0]
End starting org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632 [0] 65
Time to load bundles: 57
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450 [2]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450 [2]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.200.v20160504-1450 [2] 741
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230 [86]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230 [86]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230 [86] 22
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036 [89]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036 [89]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036 [89] 62
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850 [90]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850 [90]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850 [90] 3
Finding activator for org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927 [53]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions_0.14.0.v20160211-1614 [55]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337 [133]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337 [133]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337 [133] 15
Finding activator for org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342 [47]
Starting org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342 [47]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.100.v20160418-1621 [32]
Starting org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.100.v20160418-1621 [32]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.6.1.v20160815-1406 [127]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.6.1.v20160815-1406 [127]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.6.1.v20160815-1406 [127] 37
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.100.v20160223-2218 [128]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.100.v20160223-2218 [128]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.100.v20160223-2218 [128] 529
End starting org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.100.v20160418-1621 [32] 581
Finding activator for org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.400.v20160506-0750 [185]
Starting org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.400.v20160506-0750 [185]
End starting org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.400.v20160506-0750 [185] 220
Finding activator for org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.8.0.v20160509-0411 [42]
Starting org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.8.0.v20160509-0411 [42]
End starting org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.8.0.v20160509-0411 [42] 22
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528 [84]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528 [84]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528 [84] 33
End starting org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.12.0.v20160606-1342 [47] 890
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.400.v20160504-1450 [115]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [102]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [102]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [102] 6
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher_1.1.100.v20150423-1455 [105]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher_1.1.100.v20150423-1455 [105]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.directorywatcher_1.1.100.v20150423-1455 [105] 0
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.400.v20160504-1450 [115]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher_1.4.100.v20160504-1450 [113]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher_1.4.100.v20160504-1450 [113]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher_1.4.100.v20160504-1450 [113] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.3.100.v20160427-2220 [110]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.3.100.v20160427-2220 [110]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_2.3.100.v20160427-2220 [110] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.3.200.v20160421-0324 [116]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.3.200.v20160421-0324 [116]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_2.3.200.v20160421-0324 [116] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [111]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [111]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [111] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.200.v20150715-1528 [129]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.200.v20150715-1528 [129]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.200.v20150715-1528 [129] 2
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [106]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [106]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_2.4.100.v20160419-0834 [106] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [107]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [107]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extensionlocation_1.2.300.v20160419-0834 [107] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.0.600.v20160504-1450 [126]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.0.600.v20160504-1450 [126]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite_1.0.600.v20160504-1450 [126] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.1.200.v20160606-1311 [120]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.1.200.v20160606-1311 [120]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.1.200.v20160606-1311 [120] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer_5.0.0.v20160405-1820 [73]
Starting org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer_5.0.0.v20160405-1820 [73]
End starting org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer_5.0.0.v20160405-1820 [73] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.500.v20160419-0834 [100]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.500.v20160419-0834 [100]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_1.1.500.v20160419-0834 [100] 1
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse_2.1.400.v20160419-0834 [118]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse_2.1.400.v20160419-0834 [118]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse_2.1.400.v20160419-0834 [118] 2
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.3.300.v20160504-1450 [103]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.3.300.v20160504-1450 [103]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_2.3.300.v20160504-1450 [103] 2
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector_1.0.300.v20160504-1450 [108]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector_1.0.300.v20160504-1450 [108]
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector_1.0.300.v20160504-1450 [108] 1
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins_1.1.400.v20160504-1450 [115] 1040
Finding activator for org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405 [88]
Starting org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405 [88]
Finding activator for org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036 [20]
Starting org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036 [20]
End starting org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036 [20] 54
Finding activator for org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605 [21]
Starting org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605 [21]
End starting org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605 [21] 22
Finding activator for org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215 [19]
Starting org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215 [19]
End starting org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215 [19] 14
End starting org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405 [88] 148
Starting application: 4563
Finding activator for org.eclipse.ui.ide.application_1.1.101.v20160829-0827 [171]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.108.1.v20160819-2118 [183]
Starting org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.108.1.v20160819-2118 [183]
Finding activator for com.ibm.icu_56.1.0.v201601250100 [3]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.ui_3.108.0.v20160518-1929 [163]
Starting org.eclipse.ui_3.108.0.v20160518-1929 [163]
End starting org.eclipse.ui_3.108.0.v20160518-1929 [163] 6
End starting org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.108.1.v20160819-2118 [183] 101
Finding activator for org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.4.0.v20160517-1624 [67]
Starting org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.4.0.v20160517-1624 [67]
End starting org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench_1.4.0.v20160517-1624 [67] 7
Finding activator for org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench_1.2.0.v20160229-1459 [64]
Finding activator for org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.12.1.v20160823-0925 [170]
Starting org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.12.1.v20160823-0925 [170]
End starting org.eclipse.ui.ide_3.12.1.v20160823-0925 [170] 3
```